# Что я делаю не так при парсинге?

Tags: php, curl, синтаксический-анализ

Написал небольшую функцию:

```
function curl($url, $userAgent = null, $proxy = null, $referer = null)  
{  
    $curl = curl_init();  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);  
    $out = curl_exec($curl);  
    curl_close($curl);  

    return $out;
}
```

При использовании в таком виде:

```
$out = curl('http://example.com/page.html');
echo $out;
```

Иногда, данный код работает отлично, иногда не очень, объясняю: Допустим, я имею сайт вида mysite.ru/index.php, когда я пытаюсь спарсить страницу page.html с сайта example.com, то по какой-то причине меня перекидывает на страницу-донор, т.е. mysite.ru/page.html не понимаю, с чем это может быть связано, может установлена какая-то защита?

Comment: скажите пожалуйста, какой смысл вы вложили в термин «страница-донор»? просто это незнакомое мне сочетание (в таком контексте), и, возможно, вложенный вами смысл имеет ключевое значение.

Comment: а причём тут синтаксический анализ, простите?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin страница-донор я имел в виду страницу сайта, с которого требуется взять информацию.

Comment: @VladD ставил тег "парсинг", не очень понимаю, как сайт так заменил данный тег.

Comment: *страница-донор я имел в виду страницу сайта, с которого требуется взять информацию* — извините, совсем сбился с толку. вы назвали "страницей-донором" адрес `mysite.ru/page.html`. как я понял, это какая-то страница на **вашем** сайте, и **никакого** отношения к параметру, передаваемому функции `curl`, она не имеет. или всё-таки имеет?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin имеется в виду, что страница `page.html` не существует на моем сайте, после запуска скрипта с адресом `mysite.ru/script.php` она превращается в `mysite.ru/page.html`

Comment: *ставил тег "парсинг", не очень понимаю, как сайт так заменил данный тег* — метка [tag:парсинг] описана как [синоним](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7/synonyms) для метки [tag:синтаксический-анализ]

Comment: *после запуска скрипта с адресом mysite.ru/script.php* — а в этом скрипте и вызывается ваша функция `curl`?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin именно

Comment: @hrvasiliy, так сохраните вывод функции `curl` в файл. чтобы было видно, что именно она вернула, без последующей обработки результата апачем и браузером.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin сделал, там один довольно большой JS скрипт и все. Информация, которая имеется в действительности - нет.

Comment: @hrvasiliy, там не может быть *один* только javascript. по крайней мере в начале файла должны быть заголовки, которые вернул сервер, к которому вы обращались (если вы, конечно, по моему совету поменяли значение `CURLOPT_HEADER` на `1`).

Comment: но, кстати, вот вам и объяснение «странностей»: сервер вернул javascript, ваш скрипт передал его вашему серверу, ваш сервер вернул его в ваш браузер, ваш браузер попытался его выполнить, а в javascript-е присутствует, например, команда перехода на адрес `/page.html`.

Comment: В файле говорится о том, что требуется включить JS. Некоторое время не буду иметь доступа к ПК. Позже, попробую провести эти же действия, только буду использовать PhantomJS. Завтра отпишу о результате.

Comment: @hrvasiliy, чтобы я получил нотификацию, упомяните меня в ответе: `@имя`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin По какой-то причине с PhantomJS все точно так же. Требует JS, хотя он есть и точно работает. Вообще не понимаю, в чем причина.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Бред. PhantomJS работает так же, как и обычный браузер.

Comment: @hrvasiliy, вы смотрите в html-код скачанной страницы и видите текст о том, что «javascript отключен»? это довольно распространённая практика работы: выводить на странице такое уведомление **и** скрывать его приложенным javascript-ом: если javascritp разрешён в вашем браузере, то вы просто не увидите этого уведомления: оно будет скрыто.

Comment: В PhantomJS включен JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была решена так:
1. Отследил какие данные отправляются на сайт.
2. Отправил эти данные POST запросом.

```
$post_data = array (  
    'one' => 'something',  
    'two' => 'something',  
    'three' => 'something'  
);
```

В опциях CURL добавил:

```
// POST запрос  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  
// Переменные  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
```

Answer (score -1):

> с чем это может быть связано?

например, с тем, что вы явно указали `curl`-у следовать по адресам, возвращаемым серверами в заголовке `location:`:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

если вы измените значение на `0`, то переходов не будет. правда, этот вариант может не подойти в том случае, если таковой переход действительно нужен.

---

дальнейшие поиски «неисправностей» стоит продолжить с просмотра заголовков, возвращаемых сервером(-ами). для того, чтобы они попали в вывод `curl_exec`, надо изменить значение `CURLOPT_HEADER` на `1`:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
```

---

чтобы увидеть то, что функция `curl` на самом деле вернула, нужно сохранить её вывод в какой-нибудь файл.

т.е., после её вызова:

```
$out = curl('http://example.com/page.html');
```

добавьте строку такого примерно вида:

```
file_put_contents('/tmp/some.file', $out);
```

и после отработки скрипта смотрите результат в файле `/tmp/some.file`.

Comment: Такой вариант не подходит, попробовал, все так и осталось.

Comment: дополнил ответ.

Comment: Опять же, никакого результата, единственное, что происходит: смена ссылки на моей странице со скриптом, на ту ссылку, по которой пытаюсь получить информацию (остается в ссылке лишь мой домен).

Comment: У вас постоянно один и тотже урл или урлы меняются?

Comment: Покажите при каких урлах пытается смотреть на страницу на вашем сайте: ПРИМЕР В СТУДИЮ